# AndroidStudio was not right after change code

Tags: android, android-studio

Situation:

I use Android studio, when i change a line of code in it sometimes it was wrong, the code i just change is not work it still run my old version code.

such as

```
int a = 1;//old version 
int a = 2;//new version
```

sometimes a still value 1 when i run the new version code.

fix:

I know i can clean the project and restart Android Studio to fix it, but why it's happened?

My Question:

It's just a AS bug or something i was wrong in my project setting?

For more detail example:

I have class a with the method putLog() like below

```
private void putLog()
{
    Log.i("tag","string");
}
```

Then i find i don't need the Log.i("tag","string") anymore, so i delete it

```
private void putLog()
{
   // Log.i("tag","string");
}
```

but after i delete it, the log output is still there, my delete is not work.
I restart Android Studio and clean the cache, the log is not show anymore.

Comment: how you are trying to change the version code, may be there is some logic issue

Comment: just a sample to explain my problem,  it means i change the a value to 2

Comment: check that value in the start of your app, i think it work

Comment: @Sree  I add a more detail example to explain my problem, please check it,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's mainly because i have use multiple-channel gradle script to generate apk, now i remove it, it not show again.